# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onCreate_Clicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: android-studio

I created a Fragment using **Android Studio 3.6.2**. Fragment has a **Button** called  ‘create’. But when I click on that button( even though I had linked button to that method)  it fails with

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onCreate_Clicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'create'

Click method of Button in Fragment

```
public void onCreate_Clicked(View caller) {
    create = getView().findViewById(R.id.create);
    create.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Button part in corresponding xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/create"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="328dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="240dp"
    android:onClick="onCreate_Clicked"
    android:text="Create"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I did see similar questions but none of the answer in those post did not help.
Could someone please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an activity you can declare the onclick (as you declared`android:onClick="onCreate_Clicked"`)attribute in XML and can call the method but in fragment`android:onClick="onCreate_Clicked"` will not called .

Possible Solutions:

1. First case you have to declare a method `onCreate_Clicked`in your activity from where you are calling the fragment.
2. Implement `onClickListener` programatically to handle the click event in button.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I did    createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { ...} } and it worked fine